# Predefined routes doesn't work, why?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, controller, routes

I'm about to implement functionality for editing a project, but I can't get the route to work.

**routes.rb:**

```
Ampta::Application.routes.draw do
  get "home/index"

  resources :projects
  resources :tickets
  resources :projects_users
  resources :users

  ...
end
```

**the view that's linking to the path:**

```
...
<%= link_to "Show tickets", tickets_path%><br/>
<%= link_to "Manage projects", edit_project_path %><br/> // <--- The link
<%= link_to "Log out", signout_path, method: "delete"%>
...
```

(I have defined the action 'edit' in the project controller, but it doesn't yet contains any code.)

When running rake routes, the route is there so why do I get the following error explaining that's not the case:

```
No route matches {:action=>"edit", :controller=>"projects"}
```

Comment: pass the project id/object to `edit_project_path` method like `<%= link_to "Manage projects", edit_project_path(:id) %>` or `<%= link_to "Manage projects", edit_project_path(@project) %>` if `@project` is defined.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`edit_project_path` doesn't know which project you mean to edit. This routing helper would take a `Project` instance, which it would then route to like `/projects/1/edit`. Perhaps you meant to use `projects_path`?

The `projects_path` method would go to `ProjectsController's` `index` action, which is where (typically) a list of projects are provided with links to edit them on that page.

Answer (score 2):

You need to pass in the record of the item being edited.
In your show.html.erb you'd ideally have something like;

```
<%= link_to "Manage project", edit_project_path(@project) %>
```

and in your controller

```
def show
  Product.find(params[:id])
end
```